# Ho do I measure detailed response "Performance/Navigation Timing" with Apache HTTP Client?

Tags: java, http

how can I measure timing for these parts:
`waitTime, tcp, dns, timeToFirstByte`.

As it described in https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/

I cannot find any option.

I know to measure whole request time. But I need more details.

Thanks.